# Why input element is not getting focus?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid community edition in angular project. Requirement was to enable inline editing on tab, it was achieved, but there is another requirement which is, when navigating through tab and reached to last column and hit tab key again it should create an empty row and focus to 1st element of new row as well. I'm able to push new data through ag-grid function setRowData(data).

I tried startEditingCell() and setFocusedCell() available in grid api. They do focus on element but cursor in input element does not appear.

```
import {
    Component, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {GridOptions, StartEditingCellParams} from "ag-grid-community";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-angular-grid',
  templateUrl: './angular-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./angular-grid.component.css']
})
export class AngularGridComponent implements OnInit {

  gridOptions:GridOptions;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeGridOption();
  }


  initializeGridOption() {
    this.gridOptions = {
      onGridReady: (params)=> {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      },
      rowData: this.rowData,
      columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
      rowSelection: 'multiple',
      onCellEditingStopped: function (params) {
        let rowIndex = params.rowIndex;
        let rowDataLength = this.rowData.length;
        let colId = params.column.getColId();
        if (rowDataLength === rowIndex + 1 && colId === 'price') {
          let data = {id: this.rowData.length + 1, make: '', model: '', price: ''};
          this.rowData.push(data);

          params.api.setRowData(this.rowData);
          setTimeout(() => {
            params.api.startEditingCell({rowIndex: rowDataLength, colKey: 'make'});
            params.api.setFocusedCell(rowDataLength, 'make');

          });
        }
      }
    };
  }

  columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: '',
      width: 40
    },
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', editable: true},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', editable: true},
    {
      headerName: 'Price',
      field: 'price',
      editable: true
    }
  ];

  rowData = [
    {id: 1, make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000},
    {id: 2, make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000},
    {id: 3, make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000}
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set the cell focus by `setFocusedCell`.

Check this sample plunk I've created: [<kbd>Cell Editing</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/eI4h58ltsgiKPTLEaeiu?p=preview)

Reach till the last cell and hit tab and observe that the `input` is already focused.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  params.api.startEditingCell({rowIndex: rowDataLength, colKey: 'make'});
  //params.api.setFocusedCell(rowDataLength, 'make');
});
```

Comment: Yes, its working, also I had to move the `editable=true` from column definition to default column definition. I don't know the reason but it is working.

Comment: I observed here, it is working on plunker only. Did you try it on machine as well?

Comment: it works. try reproducing it on plunk if any other thing you've missed

Comment: not able to produce on plunk, as plunk view port focus stays in window. I copied all the code and ran it on machine, it does not get focus on last tab. But when I place button element below the grid directive it start getting focus on last column. Strange but it works, I just need to find some justification why do I need to put some extra element below grid.